# Asyncio shared object at the same address does not hold same values

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Okay, so I am created a DataStream object which is just a wrapper class around asyncio.Queue. I am passing this around all over and everything is working fine up until the following functions. I am calling ensure_future to run 2 infinite loops, one that replicates the data in one DataStream object, and one that sends data to a websocket. here is that code:

```
def start(self):
    # make sure that we set the event loop before we run our async requests
    print("Starting WebsocketProducer on ", self.host, self.port)
    RUNTIME_LOGGER.info(
        "Starting WebsocketProducer on %s:%i", self.host, self.port)
    #Get the event loop and add a task to it.
    asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

  asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(self._mirror_stream(self.data_stream))
    asyncio.ensure_future(self._serve(self.ssl_context))enter code here
```

Ignore the indent issue, SO wont indent correctly.

And here is the method that is failing with the error 'Task was destroyed but it is pending!'. Keep in mind, if I do not include the lines with 'data_stream.get()' the function runs fine. I made sure, the objects in both locations have the same memory address AND value for id(). If i print the data that comes from the await self.data_stream.get() I get the correct data. However after that it seems to just return and break. Here is the code:

```
async def _mirror_stream(self):
    while True:
        stream_length = self.data_stream.length
        try:
            if stream_length > 1:
                for _ in range(0, stream_length):
                    data = await self.data_stream.get()
            else:
                data = await self.data_stream.get()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
        # If the data is null, keep the last known value
        if self._is_json_serializable(data) and data is not None:
            self.payload = json.dumps(data)
        else:
            RUNTIME_LOGGER.warning(
                "Mirroring stream encountered a Null payload in WebsocketProducer!")
        await asyncio.sleep(self.poll_rate)enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by implementing my own async Queue by utilizing the normal queue.Queue object. For some reason the application would only work if I would 'await' for queue.get(), even though it wasnt an asyncio.Queue object... Not entirely sure why this behavior occured, however the application is running well, and still performing as if the Queue were from the asyncio lib. Thanks to those who looked!